# Is it possible to retrieve the "profile" of one file, and use it to convert another file?

Tags: ffmpeg

So we have an *ancient* compiled program that has been converting AVI files to MPEG for television broadcast.  The program is pure sorcery, as the original programmer is long gone, but it has created 10's of thousands of MPEG files of a very particular format that our (also ancient) broadcast server uses.

So...the question is whether or not, we can use FFMPEG to initially "get the details" of one of those MPEG files, and use THAT to convert future MP4 files to that legacy MPEG format?

In short, we don't know all the intricacies of everything that the program is or may be doing, and want to replace it with FFMPEG, being confident that we're getting exactly the same output that works without a hitch in the fussy broadcast server.

Comment: No, this has to be done manually. That said, if your server expects a standard vanilla MPEG file, then ffmpeg or some other program should be able to work.

Comment: Thank you...apparently they spent weeks getting the output "just right", and I was hoping this might allow us to bypass that potential hurdle.  If you post that as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it when allowed.

Answer (score 1):

FFmpeg cannot automatically retrieve and store all information from an existing file which is salient to reproducing those features in a new instance.

ffprobe or ffmpeg will show you basic stream and metadata information but that information has to be parsed outside of ffmpeg and then a conversion command manually crafted to reproduce those properties. However, this is only a start. There may be many aspects, like those related to flags, headers and packetization that ffprobe won't show, and which a fussy consumer expects in a certain way.

FFmpeg should be able to produce a standard vanilla file. You mention 'MPEG' but that could refer to MPEG-1/2 Program Stream (ISO 11172) or Transport Stream (ISO 13818). The latter is still widely produced & used and you should be able to find multiple software, FLOSS or otherwise, that produce it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ffprobe to get information about any AV media file and retain this information for later use:

https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FFprobeTips

If you have ffmpeg installed on your system than ffprobe should already be installed ...